# Extract post category except one category

Tags: categories

My posts are in two categories - one that defines their type eg. `article` or `review` and the other defines the topic - `tablets`,`smartphones`,`smartwatches`, etc.

How can I get the current post's category ID for its topic - i.e. whether it's a `tablet`, `smartphone` or `smartwatch`.

If I do `get_the_category( $post->ID );` I suppose it'll return all categories the post is in, but how do I filter out the `article` or `review` categories out?

Example: Post `ABC` is in categories `article` with `ID=1` and `tablets` with `ID=10` how can I extract on the `tablets` `ID=10` category without the `article` one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply loop over the categories that you don't need. [`get_the_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) return an array of categories that the post belongs to.

With that in mind, you can do the following: (*Just remember to change `21` and `41` to your desired ID's*)

```
$categories = get_the_category();
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    if( 21 ===  $category->cat_ID || 41 === $category->cat_ID ) {
        continue;
    }else{
        echo $category->cat_ID . '</br>';
    }
}
```